# How to check if a value has been passed on to a javascript function or not

Tags: javascript, html

i have the following code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MaVFz/)

here the javascript function records the value on clicking the cells of the table and stores it in a variable.

My question is how to check whether the variable has any value before submitting the form.

NOTE: i have tried..

```
if( document.getElementById("h1").value=="null")
{
   alert("PASSWORD EMPTY");
}
```

but all in vain..any solution???

Comment: your fiddle is irrelevant.

Comment: @lbu.. yeah i know its not suitable for showing some clumsy code, but have no other options...

Comment: Try to validate your html here [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) you will benefit a lot from it.

Comment: THANKS @lbu..will use definitely try to use it..

Answer (score 0):

When an element has no value, it will simply be an empty string

```
var h1 = document.getElementById("h1");

if (h1.value == ""){
   // is empty
}
```

Comment: @lbu ... no success, the page just gets submitted on clicking the submit button even if there is no input to the javascript function..

Comment: @0x499602D2 same situation, no success

Comment: @lbu.. do you get the code??? here is the xplanation...
here the user clicks on to the individual cells to input a password.. the javascript function "fun(ind)" records and passes on to the next page upon submitting...now the page gets submitted even if the user doesn't click on the image without validating..i have to  check whether there is a value in the fun(ind) notify(alert) accordingly..

Comment: But the function i see in your fiddle doesn't do that. Can you add your code to your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!document.getElementById("h1").value)
{
   alert("PASSWORD EMPTY");
}
```